# in hosting my asp.net website on free hosting providers the following occurs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access-2007

my site works properly on my system its insertion searching etc all things are fine. i hosted my site on brinkster.com when i access my site from the provided url all other pages work except those which are connected to my ms access database. i don't know how to fix it.

**this is the stack trace which i recieve**

```
[OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not find file 'C:\Sites\content\mydatabase.mdb'.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) +969373
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +86
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) +29
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +4863708
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() +40
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen(IDbConnection connection, ConnectionState& originalState) +31
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +112
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +287
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +92
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1297
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.AccessDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +58
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +142
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +73
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +22
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +17
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +80
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842
```

Answer (score 1):

your DB needs to be on the server, not your local drive.  If you HAVE uploaded the .mdb, then change the references from the absolute c:\sites\content........ to a relative ..(folder where the db is)(dbfilename).mdb

Answer (score 1):

Is the .mdb file on ther server?   If it is then make sure in you webconfig , or whereever you have a connection string set change it from `C:\Sites\content\mydatabase.mdb'`  to where it actually  is